# How do I to expose all properties of a public function in a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is my plugin (trying to allow for designers to easily add Flowplayer to my sites)

```
 (function ($) {
     $.fn.irvVideoPlayer = function (options) {

         var settings = $.extend({
             'fpKey': '#@12345678905',
             'videoPath': 'path-to-my-video.mp4',
             'seekTo': 1,
             'autoPlay': true,
             'src': "/flash/flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.9.swf"
         }, options);

         return this.each(function () {

             var $this = $(this);

             var firstTimeVisitor, playedOnce;

             firstTimeVisitor = function () {
                 if ($.cookie("videoplayerhome") == null) {
                     firstTimeVisitor = null;
                     $.cookie("videoplayerhome", "Video Loaded", {
                         path: "/",
                         expires: 30
                     })
                 } else {
                     this.seek(settings.seekTo).pause();
                     $.cookie("playedOnce", "User Pressed Play");
                 }
             }

             playedOnce = function () {
                 if ($.cookie("playedOnce") == null) {
                     playedOnce = null
                 } else {
                     $f().seek(0);
                     $.cookie("playedOnce", null);
                 }
             };

             fpPlayer = {
                 src: settings.src,
                 wmode: "transparent"
             };

             this.fpConfig = {
                     key: settings.fpKey,
                     plugins: {
                         controls: {
                             autoHide: false,
                             background: "#272D6A",
                             backgroundGradient: "none"
                         },
                         lighttpd: {
                             url: "/flash/flowplayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.9.swf"
                         }
                     },
                     clip: {
                         provider: "lighttpd",
                         autoBuffering: true,
                         ipadUrl:  settings.videoPath + "/playlist.m3u8",
                         autoPlay: settings.autoPlay
                     },
                     onStart: firstTimeVisitor,
                     onResume: playedOnce,
                     playlist: [{
                         url: settings.videoPath
                     }],
                     canvas: {
                         background: "#000000",
                         backgroundGradient: "none"
                     }
                 }


             $(this, fpPlayer, this.fpConfigSetup()).ipad();

         });

         return this.initialize();

     };
 })(jQuery);
```

And I am able to use this plugin like this:

```
$('#homePageVideo').irvVideoPlayer({
seekTo: 10
});
```

Great!, but at times I am needing to get to all the properties set in fpConfig, and would like to be able to do something like this:

```
fpConfig.plugins.controls.all = false;
fpConfig.plugins.controls.play = true;
fpConfig.plugins.controls.scrubber = true;
fpConfig.canvas.background = "#444444"
// etc....
```

Comment: You have both an instance property called `fpConfig`, which refers to a function, **and** a variable called `fpConfig`, which refers to an object. I'd *really* recommend giving them different names. Also, why do you reset `fpConfig` (the object) every time someone calls `fpConfig` (the function)?

Comment: Thank you T.J., I edited the function name, I am not sure what you are referring to with resetting the fpConfig everytime the function is called. This is my first jQuery plugin, and your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @ Jeffrey: The `fpConfigSetup` function closes over the `fpConfig` variable. In that function, you're doing `return fpConfig = { ... }`, which means that any time the function is called, it will overwrite `fpConfig` with the `{ ... }` object, and then return a reference to that (new) object. (This particular bit has nothing to do with jQuery, just JavaScript.)

Comment: I am not sure about how to overcome this, T.J., thank you for your input.

Comment: After revisiting it with a fresh set of eyes (sortof), I think I resolved what you are referring to T.J. However, I am still unclear on how to manipulate the properties within this.fpConfig after the plugin has been initialized. Really frustrating.